# .htaccess exception for subdomain not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, exception, redirect, subdomain

I want to redirect the root of my website to a subfolder using .htaccess

#### Should be:

mysite.com -> Redirects to **mysite.com/2015**
mysite.com/something -> **No Redirect**
sub.mysite.com -> **No Redirect**

What currently happens is that sub.mysite.com is being redirected as well to mysite.com/2015.

This is my current .htaccess. Already tried a dozen exceptions for the subdomain, none of them worked.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect WWW to non-WWW, vice versa
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
  
# Some security rules
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options +Indexes
AcceptPathInfo Off

#Custom 404 Page
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# Video types for mobile
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

# Invoice Redirect
RewriteRule ^b/(.*)$ ./modules/gateways/boletocefsinco/boleto_cef_sigcb.php?via=$1 [L,NC]

# New Site Redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2015/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /2015/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ 2015/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache or try a different browser? You should also escape your `.` in the RewriteCond.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it. I'll leave an answer for you to accept so the question isn't left unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear your browser cache or try different browsers when testing .htaccess rules as these things get cached.

Also you can use `[R=302,L]` in your rewriterule if doing actual redirecting while testing then you can remove the 302 when you see it works.